# How to use HTML5shiv with ajax calls data results

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html5shiv

i'm  making an ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
      url: action,
      cache:false,
      success: function(data){

                  alert($(data).find("*").html());

    }

});
```

all browsers (exept  IE 8  and  7) displays correctly the alert  i put inside the SUCCESS. in IE i get an "undefined" message.

data contains some HTML5 tags and i know that is for that reason why  it  doesn't work.

I've already put HTML5shiv in my header but it works for the normal pages and not for ajax calls.

How can i call HTML5shiv on my "data" results?

i've already tried with innerShiv as well, but the author says that it is not reccomended anymore because html5shiv now patches for the innerHTML issue (http://jdbartlett.com/innershiv/)

many thanks, i'm going crazy with this issue...

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? Success has been deprecated as of 1.8, you should try to use .done() instead.

Other than that, can you please make a working example in JSFiddle or CodePen, so we can test the issue?

Also: can you paste the output you get in the other browsers? I suspect something is wrong with the charset or something similar.